# Extra space between articles and footer

Tags: html, css

I don't know why there is a quiet large space between content and footer here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWgaE/4/)

I've set `margin-bottom`, `padding-bottom` of content and `margin-top` and `padding-top` of footer are zero. But why it still have a space?

Comment: You forgot to remove the default margin on the `<p>` within the `<footer>`

Comment: You'll also need to remove the default margin bottom on the last p tag of the content div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the classical behavior of collapsing margins between the `p` tags in the content and footer.

You can fix this many ways, an example of which is:

```css
body #container #wrapper {
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    padding: 67px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #969696;
    overflow: auto;
}
body #container footer {
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Set `overflow: auto` on your `footer` and `#wrapper` elements.

Also, set the height to auto on your footer to allow enough space for your text.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9jMrR/

However, you have a box shadow at the bottom of you wrapper and you need to decide how you want that to work.  If you want it to be visible, you will need to add a top margin to your footer.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a bad way of doing this but you can apply a css rule of margin-top:-10px to decrease the space between the content and the footer tag.

```
footer{
margin-top:-10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative margin:

```
footer { 
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```